# Eclipse EE + Webstorm development: enable automatic update of static web files on server

Tags: javascript, eclipse, tomcat, webstorm

I'm working on a servlet/web services website, deployed in Tomcat 7.

The website is a single page application. Html/Css/JavaScript files are served as static content by the server, and then all the ajax calls are managed by Java webservices.

I'm using Eclipse for coding in Java, and WebStorm for HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

My problem is that changes made with WebStorm are not immediately reflected on the server, making it difficult to debug (changes made with Eclipse are immediately updated in the deployed site, however). WebStorm works on exactly the same files and folders as Eclipse, not on a copy.

Is it possible to configure the projects so that changes made with WebStorm are reflected in the server, without having to touch Eclipse?

Best,

Eloy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

refresh your project in eclipse, or edit your static files with eclipse.

this is because the tomcat in eclipse publish the project in a temp folder to deploy it in tomcat.

you can also try to: open the tomcat server in the eclipse view "servers" by double clicking on it, and select the option "Serve modules without publishing"

Comment: Your first solution is what I'm trying to avoid. But the second about enabling "Serve modules without publishing" did the trick! 

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

*Window-Preferenc-Workspac*, check Refresh using native hooks or polling.

But you still **need** to wait **2-3**seconds,and need to **refresh** your browser.

I am looking for a tool that can help me refresh broswer after code change.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thanks for your advice.